# При установке parrot security os с флешки возникает проблема

Tags: linux, grub, kali-linux, parrot, parrot-os

[image: Вот так это выглядит]При установке Parrot security os с флешки на стадии выбора действий не тот загрузчик ну тоисть при выборе Live, persistence install и т.д.
Если что пробовал разные проги исошник с официального сайта.
Ещё на ноуте стоит кали рядом с виндой.
+Когда пробуешь нажать лайв и зайти в систему там просит Нажать любую клавишу.
А после того как ты нажымаешь тебе вылазит это обратно.
Это скорее всего изза боиса или что то такое на другом пк все нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы исправить этот ужасный баг вам нужно в биосе в легаси бут выбрать Uefi или что то такое точно не помню